# Create jQuery behind the code and execute every time on input text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to create jQuery behind the code in VB.NET and I want that code be execute each time when I change a value in my TextBox. For now I created method which is creating my function and that code look like this:

```
 Sub jQueryInsert()

    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    Dim sScript As String = ""

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAZIV, NAZIV_POLJA FROM [IZV_1] WHERE DATUM_ZATVARANJA IS NULL AND OPIS LIKE UPPER('%NOV%') ORDER BY KOEFICIJENT DESC;"
    cmd.Connection = con

    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
        cmd.Connection = con
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd

        Using ds As New DataSet

            Try
                con.Open()
                sda.Fill(ds)

                sScript = sScript & "$(function () {"
                sScript = sScript & "$(document).on(""keyup"", ""input[type=text]"", function () {"

                For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

                    sScript = sScript & "var txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA;"
                    sScript = sScript & "if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl(""txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA"").ClientID%>').value == """") {"
                    sScript = sScript & "txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA = 0;"
                    sScript = sScript & "}"
                    sScript = sScript & "else {"
                    sScript = sScript & "txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl(""txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA"").ClientID%>').value;"
                    sScript = sScript & "txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA = txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');"
                    sScript = sScript & "var sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " = " + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " * txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA;"
                    sScript = sScript & "if (sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " === 0 || sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + ")) {"
                    sScript = sScript & "sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl(""txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA_sum"").ClientID%>').val("""");"
                    sScript = sScript & "}"
                    sScript = sScript & "else {"
                    sScript = sScript & "sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + " = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl(""txtNOV_" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + "_KOMADA_sum"").ClientID%>').val(sumNOV" + Row(columnName:="NAZIV_POLJA") + ");"
                    sScript = sScript & "}"
                    sScript = sScript & "}"

                Next
                sScript = sScript & "});})"

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock _
                (Me.GetType, "Registered Script", sScript, True)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write("Error:" & ex.ToString)
            Finally
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                con.Close()
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I am calling this method here:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If FormView.Visible = True Then
            jQueryInsert()
        End If
    End If
        If FormView.Visible = True Then
            jQueryInsert()
        End If
End Sub
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

This is how looks like a generated script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
     $(function () {$(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]", function () {var txtNOV_1000_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_1000_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_1000_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_1000_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_1000_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_1000_KOMADA = txtNOV_1000_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV1000 = 1000 * txtNOV_1000_KOMADA;if (sumNOV1000 === 0 || sumNOV1000 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV1000)) {sumNOV1000 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_1000_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV1000 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_1000_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV1000);}}var txtNOV_500_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_500_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_500_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_500_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_500_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_500_KOMADA = txtNOV_500_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV500 = 500 * txtNOV_500_KOMADA;if (sumNOV500 === 0 || sumNOV500 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV500)) {sumNOV500 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_500_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV500 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_500_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV500);}}var txtNOV_200_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_200_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_200_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_200_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_200_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_200_KOMADA = txtNOV_200_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV200 = 200 * txtNOV_200_KOMADA;if (sumNOV200 === 0 || sumNOV200 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV200)) {sumNOV200 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_200_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV200 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_200_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV200);}}var txtNOV_100_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_100_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_100_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_100_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_100_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_100_KOMADA = txtNOV_100_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV100 = 100 * txtNOV_100_KOMADA;if (sumNOV100 === 0 || sumNOV100 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV100)) {sumNOV100 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_100_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV100 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_100_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV100);}}var txtNOV_50_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_50_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_50_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_50_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_50_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_50_KOMADA = txtNOV_50_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV50 = 50 * txtNOV_50_KOMADA;if (sumNOV50 === 0 || sumNOV50 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV50)) {sumNOV50 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_50_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV50 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_50_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV50);}}var txtNOV_20_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_20_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_20_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_20_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_20_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_20_KOMADA = txtNOV_20_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV20 = 20 * txtNOV_20_KOMADA;if (sumNOV20 === 0 || sumNOV20 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV20)) {sumNOV20 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_20_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV20 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_20_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV20);}}var txtNOV_10_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_10_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_10_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_10_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_10_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_10_KOMADA = txtNOV_10_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV10 = 10 * txtNOV_10_KOMADA;if (sumNOV10 === 0 || sumNOV10 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV10)) {sumNOV10 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_10_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV10 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_10_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV10);}}var txtNOV_5_KOMADA;if (document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_5_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value == '') {txtNOV_5_KOMADA = 0;}else {txtNOV_5_KOMADA = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl('txtNOV_5_KOMADA').ClientID%>').value;txtNOV_5_KOMADA = txtNOV_5_KOMADA.replace(/\,/g, '');var sumNOV5 = 5 * txtNOV_5_KOMADA;if (sumNOV5 === 0 || sumNOV5 === Infinity || isNaN(sumNOV5)) {sumNOV5 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_5_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val('');}else {sumNOV5 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl('txtNOV_5_KOMADA_sum').ClientID%>').val(sumNOV5);}}});})//]]>
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you not just missing a bracket here `sScript = sScript & "};"` so it should be `sScript = sScript & "});"` It's hard to tell but I can see an opening bracket here `sScript = sScript & "$(function () {"` and tried to follow it through.

Comment: I tried with that and got this error SCRIPT1009: Expected '}'

Comment: You will need to output `sScript` and review the string as there will be some bracket missing inside your build up.

Comment: I didn't close function correctly. It should look like this sScript = sScript & "});})" but now I got this error:  0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: That's a different issue and I would investigate that and then if you are still struggling open up another question. Don't adapt this one as it will become confusing for those that chance upon it. Glad you've found your bracket though as it can be a nightmare. Also turn on **Option Strict**. It will help in the long run. You should be using `&` and not `+` to bring strings together.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the generated script?

Comment: I have just added.